# Why is events method in fullCalendar - reactjs - is rerendering on eventclicked?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have this where
events call the getCalendarData() that make an API call returns in the SuccessCallback the array of appointments that should be displayed.

But the issue is that this method is being rendered 3 times so the API called is being executed 3 times.

Also when EventClick (that opens a popup) is being clicked, the getCalendarData() is being called 12 times for no reason and therefore the API is getting executed 12 times.

```js
        const appointmentsarray = [];

     const seeEventAppointment = value => {

        setSeeAppointment(true);
        let b = moment(value.event.start, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm");
        var now = b.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"); // 2019-11-22T00:00
        console.log("time", now);

        let compare = moment(value.start).isBefore();

        if (compare === false) {
          setPreviousDate(true);
          setReadText(false);
        } else {
          setPreviousDate(false);
          setReadText(true);
        }

        setDateTime(now);
        setOldDate(now);
        setIdPatient(value.id);
        setDescription(value.event._def.extendedProps.description);
        setSearchText(value.event._def.title);

        var y =
          "Title:" +
          value.event._def.title +
          "/n" +
          "Name: " +
          value.event._def.title +
          "/n Description:" +
          value.event._def.extendedProps.description ;
          console.log("y", y);
      };

        const getCalendarData = (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback)=> {
             appointmentsarray.length = 0;  
             API.getAppointmentsApi().then(response => {
                   for (let i = 0; i < response.data.appointments.length; i++) {
                   let appointmentDate = response.data.appointments[i].date;
                   let changeFormatDate = moment(appointmentDate, "DD/MM/YYYY 
                    HH:mm:ss");
                   var now = changeFormatDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
                   let o = {title: 
                          response.data.appointments[i].patient_info.first_name 
                            + " " +
                          response.data.appointments[i].patient_info.last_name,
                           start: now,
                           id: response.data.appointments[i].id,
                           description: 
                             response.data.appointments[i].description};
                                };

                     appointmentsarray.push(o);
                              }
                    successCallback(appointmentsarray);
         })
                            .catch(e => {
                              failureCallback("Failed to load");
                              setLoader(false);
                              console.log(e.response);
                            });
                      };



            return (

                     <FullCalendar
                                  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                                  header={{
                                    left: "prev,next today",
                                    center: "title",
                                    right: ""
                                    // dayGridMonth,listWeek"
                                  }}
                                  plugins={[
                                    dayGridPlugin,
                                    timeGridPlugin,
                                    interactionPlugin,
                                    bootstrapPlugin,
                                    listPlugin
                                  ]}
                                  ref={calendarComponentRef}
                                  dateClick={openDateList}
                                  editable={true}
                                  eventStartEditable={false}
                                  eventResizableFromStart={true}
                                  eventDurationEditable={true}
                                  dragRevertDuration={true}
                                  eventLimit={4}
                                  slotDuration={30}
                                  eventClick={seeEventAppointment}
                                  events={(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) =>
                                    getCalendarData(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback)
                                  }

                                />


            )
```

Comment: The code shown, by itself, would not cause the problem described, as far as I can see. Perhaps the issue is elsewhere, maybe in one of the functions referenced here. Have you tried to debug and narrow down the issue at all?

Comment: I just edited the code and added the methods. 
I tried to debug but couldn't get anywhere